# get focused element on blur in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I cannot find the answer to my question. Please send me a link if you know where it has already been answered.

I am using jquery to bind a function to the onblur event of a textbox.
The objective is to trigger a postback only when the focus leaves the textboxes in the `tblUserDetails` table. 
When a textbox loses focus:

- In IE, the new focused element is the new selected textbox.
- In Chrome, document gets focused in between the two textboxes, so that `$(document.activeElement)` never points to the newly selected textbox.

Here is my code, which works in IE, but not in Chrome:

```
SaveNetworkDetails: function () {

    // Trigger the blur event when one of the textboxes loses focus
    $("[id$=tblUserDetails]").find('input[id*="txt"]').blur(function (e) {

        // Check if the new focused element is among the textboxes
        if ($(document.activeElement).parents("[id$=tblUserDetails]").length == 0) {
            // Trigger postback
        }
    });
}
```

How can I find the newly selected textbox in Chrome in the function bound to the blur event?

Regards,

Gilles

Comment: I think Chrome is doing the right thing. The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/editing.html#focus-management) says that when assigning focus to a new element, you first run the "unfocusing steps" for the old one. They are separate operations, and the blur event occurs before the new element becomes active. I don't think you're intended to be able to access the new target in a blur handler.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the interesting link. I would disagree with you. The same documentation says "When an element that is focused stops being a focusable element, or stops being focused without another element being explicitly focused in its stead, the user agent should synchronously run the focusing steps for the body element, if there is one". In my case, another textbox is explicitly focused, so the browser shouldn't have to focus on document in between. Or at least it should let me access the new focused-on textbox as the one that initiated the blur event.

Comment: I don't see how that paragraph changes the fact that step 3 of the focusing steps (make the new element the focused element) doesn't happen until _after_ step 2 (run the unfocusing steps on the old element). "Synchronously" doesn't mean "simultaneously". At best, this leaves it unclear what should be the active element while the unfocus event is running when you're moving focus to a new element.

Comment: I agree. To my mind, the paragraph implies that the body should not be focused on if another element has been explicitly focused on. But steps 2 and 3 seems to contradict with my statement. So, I believe the specifications are not forcing any behaviour. Thanks for your help though, at least it shows me how much I have still to learn.

Comment: Since HTML5 is still a work in progress, maybe you can send feedback to them and this will be clarified. But that won't help you for now, it's empirically true that browsers differ in this behavior and you have to work around it (maybe also submit an enhancement request to jQuery, they might be able to do something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small misconception here: [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) does not trigger the blur event, it binds a function to the blur event, meaning you set a function that will be triggered when the blur occurs.

Perhaps that misconception is the root cause of your issue.

**Update**

I've re-read the question and now I see what you are trying to achieve. Although your text leads one to think you are programatically triggering the blur, your issue is the fact that, in chrome, the document gets the temporary focus when a control is left.

Instead of triggering the postback on the first input's blur, you should trigger the postback on the next input's focus. By what I see in your code, this change would not matter much, but would solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Adrian. Sorry for not using the right terminology. The event gets triggered and the function bound to the event is called. My issue is more with the fact that the change on focus seems to be done in one step in IE (going from the element that lost focus to the one that gained it) and in two steps in Chrome (going from the element that lost focus to document and then from document to the element that gained focus). In the function bound to the blur event, I can access the element that gains focus in the first step (i.e. document in Chrome), but not to the final element. Gilles

Comment: Adrian. This sounds like a brilliant idea. I think I lost track of what I was doing. Let me try to do it as you suggested and I'll mark this as the answer.